# Complex number exercise

Tags: complex-numbers

This is the exercise :

Express the following complex numbers in the form $a+bi$ , where $a$ and $b$ are real integers

(I) $(2+i)^4$

(ii) $(1-i)(2 + i )^4$

Hence , (iii) find exactly the argument of $(2+i)^4 $

(iii) deduce that $\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{31}{17}\right) + \tan^-1\left(\frac{24}{7}\right) = \frac{3\pi}{4}$

I could solve the first 2 questions exactly . Nevertheless , I'm not sure that I did rightly the 2 remain questions .

Comment: Even though you said you cannot solve it yourself, you should still try and explain what you have tried so that people know what problem you are having and what you don't understand

Comment: Hint: $\;(2+i)^2=2^2 + 2 \cdot 2i + i^2=3+4i\,$. Repeat and simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $(2+i)^4=\left((2+i)^2\right)^2=\left(2^2+2\cdot2i+i^2\right)^2=(3+4i)^2=\left(3^2+2\cdot3\cdot4i+(4i)^2\right)=-7+24i.\implies a=-7,\ b=24,\\$
2. $(1-i)(2+i)^4=(1-i)(-7+24i)=17+31i.\implies a=7.\ b=31,\\$
3. $\arg(2+i)^4=4\cdot\arg(2+i)=4\cdot\tan^{-1}\dfrac{1}{2},\ or,$

$\arg(2+i)^4=\arg(-7+24i)=\pi-\tan^{-1}\dfrac{24}{7}$

4. $\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{31}{17}\right) + \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{24}{7}\right) =\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\frac{31}{17}+\frac{24}{7}}{1-\frac{31}{17}\cdot\frac{24}{7}}=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\frac{625}{119}}{\frac{119-774}{119}}=\tan^{-1}(-1)=\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\dfrac{3\pi}{4}.$

Comment: While this is correct, the last step isn't really something which is deduced from the previous answers, it is calculated almost as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

**(I)**

Given $z=2+i$, compute the polar form $re^{i\theta}$
$$
 r = \lvert 2 + i \rvert = \sqrt{5}, \qquad \arg = \arctan \frac{1}{2} 
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
  z^{4} &= \left( 2+i \right)^{4} \\
&=  \left( re^{i\theta} \right)^{4} = r^{4} e^{4i\theta} = \sqrt{5}^{4} \left( \cos 4\theta + i \sin 4\theta \right) = 
25 \left( -\frac{7}{25} + i \frac{24}{25} \right) \\
&= -7 + 24 i
\end{align}
$$

---

**(II)**

$$
\begin{align}
 \left( 1 -  i \right) \left( 2+i \right)^{4} 
&=
\left( 1 -  i \right)\left( -7 + 24 i \right) \\
&= (1)(-7) + (1)(i) + (-i)(-7) + (-i)(24i) \\
&= 17 + 31 i
\end{align}
$$

---

**(III)**

$$\varphi = \arg \left( 2+i \right)^{4} = \arg \left( -7 + 24 i \right) = \arctan \left( -\frac{24}{7} \right)$$

---

**(IV)**

Deduce $$\arctan 
\left( \frac{31}{17} \right) + 
\left( \arctan \frac{24}{7} \right) = 
\left( \frac{3\pi}{4} \right)$$

Multiplication of complex numbers involves summing angles:
$$
  z_{1} = r_{1} e^{i \theta_{1}}, \quad 
  z_{2} = r_{2} e^{i \theta_{2}} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad 
  z_{1} z_{2} = r_{1}r_{2} e^{i \left( \theta_{1} + \theta_{2}\right)}
$$
That is,
$$
  \arg z_{1} + \arg z_{2} = \arg \left( z_{1} z_{2} \right)
$$
In this example 
$$
 z_{1} =  -7 + 24 i, \quad z_{2} = 1 - i \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad  z_{1} z_{2} = 17 + 31 i
$$
Multiplication by $1 - i$ rotates a complex number by $-\frac{\pi}{4}$.

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
  \arg z_{1} + \arg z_{2} &= \arg \left( z_{1} z_{2} \right) \\
%
  \arctan \left(  \frac{24}{-7}\right) + 
  \arctan \left(  \frac{1}{-1}\right) &= 
  \arctan \left( \frac{31}{17}\right)  \\
%
  \pi - \arctan \left(  \frac{24}{7}\right)  
  -\frac{\pi}{4} &= 
  \arctan \left( \frac{31}{17}\right)  \\
\end{array}
$$
which rearranges to
$$\arctan 
\left( \frac{31}{17} \right) + 
\left( \arctan \frac{24}{7} \right) = 
\left( \frac{3\pi}{4} \right)$$

Comment: For (iii) is it not $\pi+\arctan\left(-\frac{24}7\right)$?

Comment: Must it be tan^-1 ( 24/7)?

Comment: the ans. in (iii) is wrong as the complex point $(-7+24i)$ is in the 2nd quadrant so, $\arg(2+i)^4=\arg(-7+24i)=\pi-\tan^{-1}\dfrac{24}{7}$.